Improving iCloud Sync Speed for SwiftData in iOS and watchOS Apps
I'm developing an iOS app (for iPhone and iPad) with a watchOS companion app using SwiftData and iCloud. I've set up the following:

SwiftData model with optional/default parameters
iCloud capability with CloudKit, using the same container for both iOS and watchOS targets
Background modes with remote notifications enabled
App Sandbox entitlement set to true

Everything syncs well across devices (iPhone, iPad, and Apple Watch). However, I'm noticing a lag in real-time synchronization (around 40 seconds), which I understand is expected given the process.
My goal is to have faster sync times, especially since I plan to include widgets.
What are some best practices or strategies to minimize sync lag with iCloud? Am I missing any important steps or configurations?
I am expecting almost instantaneous updates, but there is a noticeable lag.

If you want data to get to the watch quickly, use WCSession rather than relying on iCloud sync. The watch is a low power platform and does not prioritise network sync

Thank you for the suggestion to use Watch Connectivity. I know it's a good way to send and receive data between iOS and a paired watchOS device. However, my concern is specifically with SwiftData. I want users to be able to create, edit, and delete SwiftData objects on both devices. I am not sure how to achieve this with Watch Connectivity.

Did you try to call explicitly modelContext.save() when something "sync-worthy" happens (e.g. a user leaves the entry screen or triggers a "start/stop" of an action). This ensures that the Cloud synchronization happens ASAP.
Most of the problems I've seen so far is that people think that synchronization did not yet happen... but the problem was mainly that the (often complex) view was not automatically updating! Due to some still unfixed SwiftData bug!
